# Roblox Lua UserInputService

Tags: lua, roblox

```
UserInputService=game:GetService("UserInputService")

UserInputService.InputBegan:Connect(function(input, gameProcessedEvent)
    if input.KeyCode==Enum.KeyCode.A then
        print("U pressed A")
    end
end)
```

My code is above. Is there anything wrong with it? It doesn't display anything.

Putting local before userinputservice.

Comment: Your code is fine. Is this in a LocalScript, and is that LocalScript inside StarterPlayer > StarterCharacterScripts?

Comment: @Kylaaa yes it is

Answer (score 1):

That shoud work

```lua
local UserInputService = game:GetService('UserInputService')
UserInputService.InputBegan:Connect(function(input,gameProcessed)
  
if input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.Keyboard then
      
      if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.A then
          print("U pressed A")
      end
  
  end
end)
```

Comment: thx im gonna try that later

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @SnipeBlox: how did you get on with this? Did the answer work for you?

Comment: No my problem was a bit silly, i didnt focus on the screen after pressing on it it worked